# Getting Unwanted output when using Response.BinaryWrite(MyByte) and Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Tags: .net, vb.net, download, response

I am trying to download word documents (.docx) from Database.

So I used the following code at end of Download function

```
 Response.BinaryWrite(MyByte)
 Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

But it writes the unwanted content to my word file so it's throwing the error while opening each time of file.

> The file is corrupt and can't be open

I googled about this issue and I got Use **Response.End()** instead of **Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()**

But Response.End throw error as Thread was being aborted. and file opened perfectly.

Comment: Finally I got the solution of this by adding Response.AddHeader("content-length", mytBytes.Length.ToString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this to fix my problem

I just managed to get around this by replacing

```
Response.Clear();
```

with

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

so the whole thing looks like:

```
byte[] downloadBytes = doc.GetData();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", downloadBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFile.docx");
Response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```